# Font render after page (contents) renders

Tags: html, css, browser

My page contents are rendered before the font renders even i have placed fonts on the top
Here are my codes...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Computer Stuffs Developer Profile</title>
<?php include_once('includes.php');?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/projects.css" />
```

includes.php file contain

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine|Indie+Flower|Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--[if IE]>
        <script src="js/ie_html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/universal.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hyperlinks.css" />
```

Previously my fonts were below html5.js now i have moved it on top and i am still facing problem.. i cleared my cache and tired.

Comment: Have you tried a local downloaded font ? Test the otf/eot/svg versions.

Comment: Can i get google fonts in these formats?

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate... of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711641/avoid-delayed-load-of-font-face I suppose.

Comment: Download from google and then use an online font converter service.

Example : go to https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Indie+Flower click on the "Download fonts" arrow, choose zip format. Next search for "online font converter" and convert it to your desired format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to cache the fonts. Here is a good article about performance in loading fonts with examples:

[**Link**](http://css-tricks.com/preventing-the-performance-hit-from-custom-fonts/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a wait panel that covers the 100% of the page and on the "ready" event you can remove the panel and show the page correctly rendered.

Comment: I thought about that but is there any another way?